# For what real numbers α does there exist a constant c(α) such that the function is a pdf?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

For what real numbers $\alpha$ does there exist a constant $c(\alpha)$ such that
the function $f_ \alpha (x) = \frac{c(\alpha)}{x^{\alpha}}, x >1 $ is a probability density function?

Edit: my recent attempt was the following:
$c(\alpha) \int_{1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}} =1 $, which leads to 
$c(\alpha) \cdot \frac{1}{\alpha-1} = 1$. Would it be the final answer? Looks too simple.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

Comment: For the ones such that $x^{-\alpha}\in L^1[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider 
$$f_{\alpha} (x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{c(\alpha)}{x^{\alpha}} &\mbox{ for } x >1, \\ 
0 &\mbox{ otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
$$

In order for $f_{\alpha}$ to be a pdf, $f_{\alpha}(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\alpha}(x)dx=1$. 
It is clear that $f_{\alpha}$ is a nonnegative function. So 
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\alpha}(x)dx 
&= \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{c(\alpha)}{x^{\alpha}} dx \\
&= c(\alpha) \frac{x^{-\alpha+1}}{1-\alpha} \bigg|_{1}^{\infty} \\ 
&= \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{c(\alpha)  }{(1-\alpha)R^{\alpha-1}} - \frac{c(\alpha)}{1-\alpha} \hspace{4mm} \mbox{ when }\alpha >1\\ 
&= - \frac{c(\alpha)}{1-\alpha} = 1. 
\end{align*}
We conclude that when $\alpha >1$, $c(\alpha)=\alpha-1$ so that $f_{\alpha}$ is a pdf.

When $\alpha \leq 1$, then $\int_{[\infty,\infty]} f_{\alpha}$ does not converge; so $f_{\alpha}$ would not be a pdf.